# Microsoft.Dependency.Injection similar to Lamar For and Use function

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, lamar

I would like to ask about `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` library for IoC implementation.  Is there a way to do a similar function for the `Lamar` library function like `services.For<TService>().Use<TClient>()` in `Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection`?

My code goes like this.

```cs
public static void AddSomeServices(this IServiceCollection services, Func<SomeContext> context)
{
    // Similar to this implementation
    services.For<ISomeService>().Use(ctx => context().Extensions.SomeService);
}
```

Is there a built-in function like this in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`?

Comment: What is `context.Extensions.SomeService`? What is the type of ctx here?

Comment: It's the instance for the `ISomeService`

Comment: Have you tried `services.AddTransient<ISomeService>(ctx => context().Extensions.SomeService)`?

Comment: Hi @Steven, thank you for the comment, this is what I am looking for, but anywho, can you create an answer so I can approved as an answer here.  Thanks!